# PayWay API integration procedure in ios?

Tags: ios, api, payment-gateway

In my application, there is a payment option for user, so that they can purchase within the app.For payment I should use [PayWay](http://www.payway.com.au) gateway from Westpac(one of the Australia Bank).

In PayWay, they are providing two options.

1.NET system

2.PayWay API.

I like to use the second one(PayWay API).I got the login for testing purpose.In their website itself , they have provided some API for php,java, dot net and some other. But I dont have any idea, how this can be integrated in my ios application and where the user details should be taken(Credit card no, Password,etc) and how this can be processed.Please suggest some solution.

The actual procedure for PayWay API is,

1.Application will call the API Code which is present in our server.

2.Then our server code will call the PayWay gateway, and the response will be sent back to server from  the gateway.

3.Based on the response, we should notify the customer about the transaction.

Is my understanding correct? Please advice on this.

I have referred some S.O questions, but it doesn't help me much

[I don't understand how Westpac Payway API and NET works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785334/i-dont-understand-how-westpac-payway-api-and-net-works)

[PayWay information_fields useage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099100/payway-information-fields-useage)

[Westpac payway sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914263/westpac-payway-sample-code)

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584063/paypal-api-how-to-integrate-it-in-my-app-ios5

Comment: I don't think this will work out, you need to directly integrate the gateway to your iOS app in order to do in-app purchases. First thing is if you are submitting it to Apple App Store then rethink as Apple recommends in-app purchases through Apple.Second capturing confidential information can also cause rejection. Checkout zooz - http://www.zooz.com/developers something like this can help but also make sure those are non-consumable in-app items.

Comment: @SharonNathaniel : Do you have any idea about PayWay?

Comment: @NSUserDefault I went through the PayWay Docs and I think there is no SDK from PayWay that can be implemented in iOS. The API is for server side.

Comment: @SharonNathaniel: Yeah me too searched a lot about how to integrate it in IOS.But came with no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayWay API is a server side solution. You would need to capture credit card details in your app and send them to your backend server which would then call the PayWay API.

To use PayWay Net you would need to embed a browser control into your app. This would connect to the PayWay web page for collecting the credit card details. This way your server never handles credit card information.

I'm not sure what Apple's rules are but you should check those out too.

There is a now new functionality in PayWay which allows you to tokenise a credit card number from your iPhone App.  You still require a call from your server to trigger the payment transaction.

See [PayWay REST API Docs](https://www.payway.com.au/rest-docs/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for your response.So which is the best way to use, when its comes to mobile platform?As you said, only by getting Credit card detail from user within the app, we can perform PayWay API request, Right?

Comment: If you want to do it directly from the iPhone App to PayWay you would have to use PayWay Net.  I'm not an iPhone developer, but I believe you would need to embed a web view control into your application.  You would programatically direct it to PayWay to process the transaction.

Comment: Thank you:) Me too thought to go with NET option only.